# Lock screen image change in Windows 10

Tags: windows-8, windows-10, windows-registry

I need to change the Lock screen image.

By default, "Windows spotlight" is selected.

Is there a way to change this to "Picture" using the registry settings (regedit)?

Tried below things:

```
Set LockScreenImage = "C:\Windows\Web\Screen\img100.jpg" @ HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization
```

Placed the image what to be displayed in lock screen at:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Web\Screen\img100.jpg.
```

New users are getting this `img100.jpg` at the lock screen but not for the current user.

And also if we change to "Picture" at Personalization -> Lock screen -> Background, then `img100.jpg` is getting selected and set at the lock screen.

Comment: Are you looking specifically for a registry hack, or is using the regular method, accessing the settings enough? Since Windows 8, you can configure the lock screen image using the Settings screen.

Comment: I removed the "spotlight" tag because it is a Mac OS application.

Answer (score 1):

Scrapping my previous answer, since I see you want to do it via Registry. That's a terrible idea, registry hacking is always a last resort, since it breaks so easily. All I can say is good luck; the key you want is `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lock Screen`, but the format is completely opaque, and that's not all: The actual lock images are stored in a folder `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\SystemData\{SID}\ReadOnly\LockScreen_B`, which is normally secured for SYSTEM only.

Forget the registry, just use Powershell to [call the API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br241847); you can easily set it in 2-3 lines.