# Using a UWP API Namespace in PowerShell

Tags: windows-10, powershell, uwp

I was looking for how to use a namespace for working with the Windows 10 lock screen in PowerShell and came across this answer: https://superuser.com/a/1062551/700258, however it doesn't say anything about how to import or add that namespace to PowerShell for use. I tried looking for the referenced DLL files for the assemblies and they weren't on my computer. When I see they are part of the Windows Desktop Extensions API, I went out and downloaded the Windows 10 SDK, but the DLL files were not within that either. How can I use this LockScreen Class from the Windows.System.UserProfile namespace in a PowerShell script?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First you need to tell PowerShell that you want to use a UWP class:

```
[Windows.System.UserProfile.LockScreen,Windows.System.UserProfile,ContentType=WindowsRuntime] | Out-Null
```

The first part is the class name, the second is the UWP namespace, and the third just says that it's a UWP class. After the type is loaded, you can refer to the type by its name (just the first part: `[Windows.System.UserProfile.LockScreen]` in this case.)

The next trick is that Windows Runtime methods are asynchronous and use a different async task class than .NET Framework methods. Calling them from PowerShell requires a little extra infrastructure that I originally developed for [another answer](https://superuser.com/a/1293303/380318):

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime
$asTaskGeneric = ([System.WindowsRuntimeSystemExtensions].GetMethods() | ? { $_.Name -eq 'AsTask' -and $_.GetParameters().Count -eq 1 -and $_.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType.Name -eq 'IAsyncOperation`1' })[0]
Function Await($WinRtTask, $ResultType) {
    $asTask = $asTaskGeneric.MakeGenericMethod($ResultType)
    $netTask = $asTask.Invoke($null, @($WinRtTask))
    $netTask.Wait(-1) | Out-Null
    $netTask.Result
}
Function AwaitAction($WinRtAction) {
    $asTask = ([System.WindowsRuntimeSystemExtensions].GetMethods() | ? { $_.Name -eq 'AsTask' -and $_.GetParameters().Count -eq 1 -and !$_.IsGenericMethod })[0]
    $netTask = $asTask.Invoke($null, @($WinRtAction))
    $netTask.Wait(-1) | Out-Null
}
```

`Await` can be used to call functions that return an `IAsyncOperation`, i.e. those that produce a value. It takes the WinRT task object and the type of the output. `AwaitAction` can be used to call functions that return an `IAsyncAction`, i.e. those that just do something without returning a result. It takes only the WinRT task object.

For this application, we're going to need the [`StorageFile`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile) type accessible too:

```
[Windows.Storage.StorageFile,Windows.Storage,ContentType=WindowsRuntime] | Out-Null
```

Now we can start calling some functions. First we use [`GetFileFromPathAsync`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile.getfilefrompathasync#Windows_Storage_StorageFile_GetFileFromPathAsync_System_String_) to get an `IStorageFile` instance of the desired lock screen image:

```
$image = Await ([Windows.Storage.StorageFile]::GetFileFromPathAsync('C:\path\to\image.ext')) ([Windows.Storage.StorageFile])
```

Finally, we pass that image to [`SetImageFileAsync`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.userprofile.lockscreen.setimagefileasync#Windows_System_UserProfile_LockScreen_SetImageFileAsync_Windows_Storage_IStorageFile_) to set the lock screen background:

```
AwaitAction ([Windows.System.UserProfile.LockScreen]::SetImageFileAsync($image))
```

Changes should take effect immediately.

Comment: After hours and hours of searching in the minefield that is PowerShell, Async, Lock Screens, and Registry, your answer arose from the lake and was bathed in the light of perfection.  Honestly, it was weird.  I was searching for PowerShell & Async stuff because the actual problem I was trying to solve was scripting user lockscreen changes with SetImageFileAsync, and you managed to answer both halves at once. xxx ;-)

Comment: I wanted to thank you for posting this.  I used your trick to load the Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates Assembly

[Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates.Certificate,Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates,ContentType=WindowsRuntime] | Out-Null

and your Invoke-Async function for the Async Build Chain function.  10/10.