# Win 2012R2 Screen Lock Change

Tags: windows-server-2012

I have environment where lock screen image is embedded in **user32.dll,LockWorkStation** and would like to change it. Unfortunately whoever used this approach did not use change via GPO "Personalization" way and I cannot use this approach at the moment.
I used PS scripting from another post [Using a UWP API Namespace in PowerShell](https://superuser.com/questions/1341997/using-a-uwp-api-namespace-in-powershell/1644670#1644670) to change picture but while change is instant on win 10 it is not on win 2012R2. I can see that picture has been changed with

```
[Windows.System.UserProfile.LockScreen]::OriginalImageFile.AbsolutePath
```

but old picture is still retained.

I was playing with removal/renaming of pictures in C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\SystemData<User_Account_Security_Identifier>\ReadOnly\xxx and had mixed results.

I do not like idea of playing with permissions so question is why above script is not working in win2012R2?

Comment: Is your Windows fully updated including [this update](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-client/shell-experience/manage-lock-screen-image)?

Comment: As I mentioned I cannot use GPO approach at the moment (long chain of workflow would need to be changed).