# How can I enable the Windows Mobile Hotspot via PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, windows-11, mobile-hotspot

I'm seeking assistance with enabling the Mobile Hotspot feature on Windows 11 through PowerShell. My Wi-Fi adapter does not support the traditional `hostednetwork` feature used by the `netsh wlan` commands, as my system relies on Wi-Fi Direct to provide the Mobile Hotspot functionality.

I'm currently using `PowerShell 7.4.1` and have not been able to find a cmdlet that offers the ability to control the Mobile Hotspot feature. The Mobile Hotspot I am referring to is the one that can be manually toggled **On** or **Off** in the Windows Settings.

[image: Mobile Hotspot Toggle]

Is there a way to enable or disable the Mobile Hotspot feature on Windows using PowerShell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A PowerShell cmdlet for enabling/disabling the Mobile Hotspot is found
in the github gist
[datio/enable-wifi.ps1](https://gist.github.com/datio/e78649083f238b779f0a68526c191dda).

The script defines a PowerShell function and contains at its end
the two commands. For safety, the script is included below:

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45833873/enable-win10-inbuild-hotspot-by-cmd-batch-powershell/60444585#answer-60444585
[Windows.System.UserProfile.LockScreen,Windows.System.UserProfile,ContentType=WindowsRuntime] | Out-Null

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime
$asTaskGeneric = ([System.WindowsRuntimeSystemExtensions].GetMethods() | ? { $_.Name -eq 'AsTask' -and $_.GetParameters().Count -eq 1 -and $_.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType.Name -eq 'IAsyncOperation`1' })[0]
Function Await($WinRtTask, $ResultType) {
    $asTask = $asTaskGeneric.MakeGenericMethod($ResultType)
    $netTask = $asTask.Invoke($null, @($WinRtTask))
    $netTask.Wait(-1) | Out-Null
    $netTask.Result
}

# https://stackoverflow.com/a/55563418
$connectionProfile = [Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation,Windows.Networking.Connectivity,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]::GetInternetConnectionProfile()
$tetheringManager = [Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators.NetworkOperatorTetheringManager,Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]::CreateFromConnectionProfile($connectionProfile)

# Be sure to include Ben N.'s await for IAsyncOperation:
# https://superuser.com/questions/1341997/using-a-uwp-api-namespace-in-powershell

# Check whether Mobile Hotspot is enabled
$tetheringManager.TetheringOperationalState

# Start Mobile Hotspot
Await ($tetheringManager.StartTetheringAsync())([Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators.NetworkOperatorTetheringOperationResult])

# Stop Mobile Hotspot
#Await ($tetheringManager.StopTetheringAsync())([Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators.NetworkOperatorTetheringOperationResult])
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution! It's worth noting that for this to work with PowerShell 7+, WinRM needs to be configured. Once WinRM is set up, the script runs successfully.