# How to call Windows API commands from the command line/powershell?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

I'm building a setup script for new computers on the company.

Some settings are set by registry, but some can only be changed with the windows API, such as (example only, I need to run many other API methods too):

```
Windows.System.UserProfile.LockScreen.SetImageFileAsync(file);
```

What is a very simple/straighforwad way to run a simpler script / powershell script that calls an API method without having to build/compile an application that calls it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change my lock screen picture automatically?](https://superuser.com/questions/1343623/how-do-i-change-my-lock-screen-picture-automatically)

Comment: You'll need to determine how make the same calls using .NET.  Here is a good resource: [Use PowerShell to Interact with the Windows API](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-interact-with-the-windows-api-part-1/)